# how to *completely* turn off automatic updates in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have disabled the services "Windows Update" and "Windows Update Medic Service" in using services.mcs. Furthermore, I made changes to the registry, creating a key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU with a DWORD (32-bit) Value "AUOptions" with value set to 2.
I still see frequent queries to ctldl.windowsupdate.com sent to my DNS server. Which services need to be disables to completely shut this down?

Comment: You are trying to argue something that can be rejected based on first principles. You cannot built a perpetual motion machine, no matter what you say, and MS cannot push updates to an offline machine. I am right, you are wrong.

Comment: Lol, you believe in magic. You believe Microsoft can push an update to an offline machine. Do you also believe in the tooth ferry?